# K-Nearest algorithem for the regreesion and classification

Tags: machine-learning

What is the exact difference between k nearest classifier and  k nearest  regression ?

What sort of data the regression will be applied? Do you know any good literature?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really knn related question, simply this model can be applied similarly in two different tasks:

- Regression http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis
- Classification http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification

In short:

- Regression - you are trying to model a function f : X -> R^n (n-dimensional continuous values )
- Classification - your are trying to model a function f : X -> {c1,c2,...,ck} (finite set of values)

Some simplest example may be:

- You want to predict tommorows exact temperature = regression
- You want to predict whether tommorow will be hot or cols = classification

These concepts are heavily connected, as one can more or less convert each problem to another:

- Regression -> Classification : represent classes as values, train model, use thresholding or softmax to convert back to classes (obviously it overcomplicates if you can use classification model directly)
- Classification -> regression : use some discretization for values, train model, use some interpolation to convert back to continuous values (obviously this loses some information)

Some nice explanation in context of decision/regression trees:
http://www.simafore.com/blog/bid/62482/2-main-differences-between-classification-and-regression-trees